# material request for this soft body object

Tags: materials

[image]

I am having some trouble getting the material just right for the look of this object.

appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: so far it is just a basic translucency shader with some subsurf. but i'm not getting that blue hue on the inside

Comment: Have you added a blue object to the inside of it?

Comment: i did not. i assumed there was a way to achieve the look without it

Comment: It's probably the easiest way to do it, since it looks the blue is actually inside of it, so putting something blue inside of yours would be the most realistic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a try, basically it's a mix between a basic color with a *Wave* texture plugged into it (perturbated by a *Musgrave)*, a *Subsurface Scattering* in order to give it this kind of translucency, a *Layer Weight* to give it emission on the circumference and a bit of *Emission* to keep the translucency even in the dark areas:

[image]

[image]